# Hiding the tabs in a DockableFrame using Jidesoft

Tags: java, tabs, hide, dockable, jide

I am stuck using JideSoft at the momemnt. I have a DockableFrame, which will have many views on it. I want to hide the tabs that let me switch between views, but I cannot figure out how. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User can right click on the tab or the title of DockableFrame to select close menu item to close it. If you refer to how to close it using API, DockingManager.hideFrame will do it.

Answer (score 0):

DockableFrame.hideFrame(String frameName) works perfectly.

If you want to hide/unhide a component inside a DockableFrame you'll need to access that component, set the visibility

```
component.setVisibility(!component.isVisible());
```

and then ask the parent DockableFrame to revalidate itself.

```
parentFrame.revalidate();
```